# ADFS site selection redirect landing page

Tags: redirect, adfs, saml

I want to know how to change the default landing page of an ADFS connected site after browsing to it from site selection.

In the pic attached you can see I have a site called "My PHP Application" and when I click to "sign in" to this site I get redirected to `https://apache-pc-sp.testad.lan`

Now, instead of just going to `https://apache-pc-sp.testad.lan` I want the redirect to go to `https://apache-pc-sp.testad.lan/SOMETHINGHERE/`

Is this possible?

Note: I do not want to put a any sort of redirect with htdocs/htaccess/apache configs/etc. It must purely be with the ADFS setup side of things.

[image: ADFS server]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into SAML relaystate. If you send some relaystate to the PHP app that it understands, it can redirect to wherever you want. Note AD FS's responsibility here after authentication is to post a token to the endpoint on the PHP app side. You have the responsibility of ensuring the PHP behaves as desired after it receives a token at the SAML endpoint on PHP app side.

So if you configure IDP initiated relay state as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127245(v=ws.10).aspx on AD FS side, and construct a URL that contains an embedded relaystate to be consumed by PHP app, you can give the end user a URL that on clicking it will authenticate at AD FS and send them direct to the intended page.

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks for putting me in the right direction. So you gotta configure the SP in simpleSAMLphp, under authsources.php and add this to the array:
'RelayState' => 'https://mywebapp.com/something/landhere'

Answer (score 0):

ADFS simply redirects to the RP configured endpoint.

So you could just change the endpoint.

You have to ensure that the endpoint knows what to do when it gets a token.